# PostgreSQL password authentication fails

Tags: postgresql, go, visual-studio-code, passwords, debian

I get a password authentication fail as i try to run my application,as i am using Linux Debian,
this how it looks like, As am pretty sure that this is my PostgreSQL password:

panic: pq: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

`goroutine 1 [running]: main.CheckError(...) /home/ibrahim/projects/golang-postgres/go.work/main.go:21 main.main()`

I've tried to configure "pg_hba.conf pg_hba.conf" to make sure if it was my password
But it didn't open either.

Comment: Look in the database servers log file to get more details on the failure.

Comment: If you can't open pg_hba, that is a text editor question, not a db question.  What is the error you get?

Comment: i get command not found

Comment: I'm also in the same situation but in a quite different environment. Inside Docker Container in Linux os via python I can't connect to DB :(